# How could i make this password get written in a text file

Tags: python, file, passwords

I want to make a program that creates passwords and then write them on a text file but the problem is that the program only writes 1 password on the textfile even tho it generates more, how i could fix this

```
import random, time,sys

#nombre = input("Plataforma: ")

Simbolo = "*><＠＆％＄＃"
letra = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
numeros = "1234567890"
mayusculas = letra.lower()




mayus,minus,nums,sim = True,True,True,False


contraseña = ""


if mayus:
   contraseña += letra
if minus:
   contraseña += mayusculas
if nums:
   contraseña += numeros
if sim:
   contraseña += Simbolo



largo = 20
cantidad = 10


while 1 == 1:


   for i in range(cantidad):
      contra = "".join(random.sample(contraseña,largo))
      print(contra)






   contra = contra +"\n"
   parar = input().lower()


   with open("prueba.txt","a") as file:
      file.write(contra)
   if parar == "s":
      sys.exit()
```

I tried doing a while loop and repeating the write function, but it didn't work, it just repeated the same password over and over again, it didn't write a different password

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are waiting for an input (`parar = input().lower()`) before you write the new password to the text file.

Here is the working solution.

```
import random, time,sys

Simbolo = "*><＠＆％＄＃"
letra = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
numeros = "1234567890"
mayusculas = letra.lower()

mayus,minus,nums,sim = True,True,True,False

contraseña = ""

if mayus:
   contraseña += letra
if minus:
   contraseña += mayusculas
if nums:
   contraseña += numeros
if sim:
   contraseña += Simbolo

largo = 20
cantidad = 10

while True:

   for i in range(cantidad):
      contra = "".join(random.sample(contraseña,largo))
      print(contra)

   contra = contra +"\n"

   with open("prueba.txt","a") as file:
      file.write(contra)
```

To stop the code from running, simply press "Ctrl + C" on your keyboard.